# Vuex не находит мутацию в импортированном модуле

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему Vuex не находит мутацию в импортированном модуле.
Выкидывает ошибку:

> vuex.esm-browser.js?5502:976 [vuex] unknown mutation type:
> TAB_INTERVIEW_START_CLICKED

**Пример с файлами:**

```js
// store/modules/index.js
import backend from '@/store/modules/backend'

const store = createStore({
  state: () => ({
    ...
  }),

  getters: {
    ...
  },

  mutations: {
    ...
  },

  actions: {
    ...
  },

  modules: {
    backend,
  },
})


// store/modules/backend/index.js
const mutations = {
  TAB_PREINTERVIEW_NEXT_CLICKED: () => {
    console.log('TAB_PREINTERVIEW_NEXT_CLICKED')
  },
  TAB_INTERVIEW_NEXT_CLICKED: () => {
    console.log('TAB_INTERVIEW_START_CLICKED')
  },
 TAB_INTERVIEW_HANG_UP_CLICKED: () => {
    console.log('TAB_INTERVIEW_HANG_UP_CLICKED')
  },
}

const actions = {
  tabinterviewStartClicked: ({ commit }) => commit('TAB_INTERVIEW_START_CLICKED'),
  tabPreinterviewNextClicked: ({ commit }) => commit('TAB_PREINTERVIEW_NEXT_CLICKED'),
  tabinterviewHangUpClicked: ({ commit }) => commit('TAB_INTERVIEW_HANG_UP_CLICKED'),
}

export default {
  mutations,
  actions,
}
```

Comment: `vuex`  какая версия?

Comment: Тоесть не важно, посмотри у тебя 3 мутации. И по имени `TAB_INTERVIEW_START_CLICKED` у тебя нету мутации. Откуда он должен видеть его?

Comment: Сорян. Благодарю. Намудрид и не заметил опечатку